# What is the best way to structure Angular application so controllers can have $state.go(..)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router

In my Angular app, each page of the app has its own folder, with its `.html` files, `app` files, and `controller` files inside it.

Kind of like

```
root
|-- index
|  |-- index.html
|  |-- index.js
|  |-- indexCtrl.js
|-- login
|  |-- login.html
|  |-- login.js
|  |-- loginCtrl.js
etc...
```

My `ui-router` logic is contained in the app in `index.js`.

What I would like to do is place some `ui-router` logic in `login.js` where I have a submit function (`ng-submit` in `login.html`) and I would like to redirect the user if login is successful.

```
loginApp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.submit = function(){

    }
```

Trouble is, I don't exactly how to manage all the imports and dependencies or if I'm doing it the best way. Should I inject `ui-router` in this app and all my apps that need to redirect states?

I fear that will make things messy. For instance, `LoginApp` is injected with `ui-router` and then `IndexApp` is injected with `LoginApp` and `ui-router` for itself.

It doesn't seem right. Is there a better way to let different apps/controllers do things to `$state` but cut back on all the injections?

Comment: why can't login & index be kept as different ui-views from the home page instead of splitting them into different modules (or)apps?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should'nt split your routings into different modules, it makes it tedious to keep up with it and is highly prone to errors.

Your main app should contain your routings to that particular app. If you really want to sub-module all components, you would be referring to the (other module's) controllers in the routing file.